# How can I create a new rails app with rails > 3.0.3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, new-operator

I am having an issue with any rails version that is after 3.0.3 when creating a new application and I would like your opinion.

First I remove rails from my system `gem uninstall rails` and follow the instructions properly. Then I install the latest version of rails `gem install rails` and everything goes fine, I get rails 3.0.7 on my system.

When I try to create a new app, here is what I get:

```
Usage:
  rails new APP_PATH [options]

Options:
  -J, [--skip-prototype]      # Skip Prototype files
  -T, [--skip-test-unit]      # Skip Test::Unit files
  -G, [--skip-git]            # Skip Git ignores and keeps
  -m, [--template=TEMPLATE]   # Path to an application template (can be a filesystem path or URL)
      [--dev]                 # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to your Rails checkout
  -b, [--builder=BUILDER]     # Path to an application builder (can be a filesystem path or URL)
      [--edge]                # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to Rails repository
      [--skip-gemfile]        # Don't create a Gemfile
  -d, [--database=DATABASE]   # Preconfigure for selected database (options: mysql/oracle/postgresql/sqlite3/frontbase/ibm_db)
                              # Default: sqlite3
  -r, [--ruby=PATH]           # Path to the Ruby binary of your choice
                              # Default: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
  -O, [--skip-active-record]  # Skip Active Record files

Runtime options:
  -q, [--quiet]    # Supress status output
  -s, [--skip]     # Skip files that already exist
  -f, [--force]    # Overwrite files that already exist
  -p, [--pretend]  # Run but do not make any changes

Rails options:
  -v, [--version]  # Show Rails version number and quit
  -h, [--help]     # Show this help message and quit

Description:
    The 'rails new' command creates a new Rails application with a default
    directory structure and configuration at the path you specify.

Example:
    rails new ~/Code/Ruby/weblog

    This generates a skeletal Rails installation in ~/Code/Ruby/weblog.
    See the README in the newly created application to get going.
```

There is no way to create a skeleton, I keep getting that menu.

If I remove 3.0.7 and switch back to 3.0.3 then everything is fine, I do get an application skeleton. If I try 3.0.4, same problem.

Any idea?

Comment: What command are you running? I can create a new skeleton with `rails new project`

Comment: Just tried a fresh rails gem (3.0.7) and everything went fine.  The output you posted is from `rails new (appname)` ?  You're sure you aren't forgetting the `new`?  `rails sometestapp` gives me the menu you pasted but `rails new sometestapp` gives me a new rails app at version 3.0.7.

Comment: @RexM @Brett I am running `rails new appname`, I double check a couple times. Since it works for you it can only be a configuration issue that I need to understand.

Comment: Run `rails -v` and check the version of the Rails binary is the one you expect.

Comment: What version of Ruby are you running?

Comment: With rails 3.0.3 (`rails -v` gives me `rails 3.0.3`) it works fine, with rails 3.0.7 (`rails -v` gives me `rails 3.0.7`) it does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since some of you confirmed that there was absolutely nothing wrong with rails > 3.0.3 I cleaned up my configuration a bit by running:

`sudo gem clean`

From what I understand it removes all the older versions of gems that you have on your system thus I ended up with rails 3.0.7 and I am now successfully able to create new apps! I can go back on my project, thanks for your help :)

Comment: Glad you were able to figure it out. I'll keep this in mind in case something like this happens to me in the future.